# C# Linq rollup child array with parent field value

Tags: c#, linq

Take the following example:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Members[] Members { get; set; }
}

public class Members
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a C# list of teams comprised of the following:

```
[
{
    "Id" : 1,
    "TeamName" : "A",
    "Members": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "FirstName": "Arthur",
            "LastName": "Nudge"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "FirstName": "Ken",
            "LastName": "Shabby"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Id" : 2,
    "TeamName" : "B",
    "Members": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "FirstName": "Spiny",
            "LastName": "Norman"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "FirstName": "Raymond",
            "LastName": "Luxury-Yacht"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

How can I write a Linq query to giva a result of Members but also with the Team Id e.g.

```
{
    "TeamId": 1,
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Arthur",
    "LastName": "Nudge"
},
{
    "TeamId": 1,
    "Id": 2,
    "FirstName": "Ken",
    "LastName": "Shabby"
},
{
    "TeamId": 2,
    "Id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Spiny",
    "LastName": "Norman"
}
```

I can return a Member list from the Team list by using 
`Teams.SelectMany(t => t.Members).ToList();` but how do I also include the TeamId

Comment: try `selectMany(x => new {Members  = ... , TeamId =... ,  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` in this way:

```
var q = Teams
    .SelectMany(t => t.Members
        .Select(tm => new{ TeamId = t.Id, tm.Id, tm.FirstName, tm.LastName }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom LINQ query to combine this into a list of anonymous objects with the fields you need:

```
var list = (from team in Teams
           from member in team.Members
           select new 
           {
               TeamId = team.Id,
               member.Id,
               member.FirstName,
               member.LastName
           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `SelectMany` and `Select`:

```
teams.SelectMany(team => team.Members.Select(member => new
      {
          TeamId = team.Id,
          MemberId = member.Id,
          member.FirstName,
          member.LastName
      })).ToList();
```

- The inner `Select` will map each member and the teams Id to an anonymous type.
- The outer `SelectMany` flattens the nested `IEnumerable<...>` into a single `IEnumerable<...>`